# Google Earth Engine API map deploy to a website

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-maps-api, maps, node-js

Can we convert Google Earth Engine code (i.e., which is written in GEE console) to JavaScript so that it can be viewed on a website/app? I have gone through the GEE API documentation (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_examples), but I did not get the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that would be to create an Earth Engine App. The link you provided is for creating custom applications, which is harder. Look at this documentation section instead:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apps

Comment: In addition, see live examples in the [Code Editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/) under the Scripts tab: Examples > User Interface

Comment: Thank you, Is there any documentation to learn about developing the custom applications(excluding developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_examples).

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with your question regarding documentation. If you are to create a custom app, there is a lot of setup to consider. HTML to add elements to a page, JavaScript to handle UI, Earth Engine Python to handle processing requests. Which of these components are you looking for assistance with?

Answer (score 0):

If my answer my be relevant to others seeking help currently, please refer this link: https://medium.com/google-earth/build-a-polished-easy-to-find-site-around-your-earth-engine-app-442040d0543c .
They have a detailed explanation to get started on embedding your app in another website.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/252348)